# Blender collada export multiple animations

Tags: blender, collada, skeletal-animation

I want to export a model with multiple actions to Collada file to use it in openGL ES2, the collada exporter exports only the selected or active action, after many researches I did not find a solution but get idea which is making actions in the same animation in different frames and separate them by the code so I added custom properties to the object to define each action start and end frame but the exporter does not export these properties too, I find a patch which enable the exporter to add custom properties but I can not build from source code  because I do not have experience in visual C++ and python, so I appreciate any solution to achieve exporting multiple animations in one dae file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way with the builtin Blender Collada exporter. I wrote my own Python exporter with the ability to grab animations from the NLA Editor and  output multiple animations as  elements in Collada. https://github.com/gregeryb/Better-Collada-1.5-DAE-export-plugin-for-Blender